# Positive measure sets $A_{1}$, $A_{2} \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $(\forall x \in A_{1})(\forall y \in A_{2}) x-y \notin \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Here's the problem in full, and what I've got so far:

> Let $E= \lbrace (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x-y \in \mathbb{Q} \rbrace$
>
> 1. Find $m(E)$, where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
> 2. Do there exist measurable sets $A_{1}$, $A_{2} \subset \mathbb{R}$ with positive Lebesgue measure such that $(A_{1} \times A_{2}) \cap E = \emptyset$?

I think I've solved $1$, but I'm stuck on $2$. Here's my solution of $1$: $E = \bigsqcup_{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \lbrace (x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | y = q+x \rbrace$, so $E$ is a countable union of lines, which are zero measure sets in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so $m(E)=0$.

I'm almost sure that the answer to $2$ is "no", but I can't get a contradiction by assuming the existence of such sets.

The only concrete thing I've got for $2$ is that for every $r_{1}$, $r_{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$, $(r_{1} + A_{1}) \cap (r_{2} + A_{2}) = \emptyset$, and if we put $r_{1} = r_{2} = 0$, we get that $A_{1} \cap A_{2} = \emptyset$. I know about [Why can't there be a bounded set with positive Lebesgue measure such that $\forall x,y$ in it, $x-y\notin\mathbb Q$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890257/why-cant-there-be-a-bounded-set-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-such-that-fora) , but I don't know how to use it here (or if I should even use it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed no, by [Lebesgue's density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem).

Suppose $m(A)>0$ and $m(B)>0$ for $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$. Then almost every $a \in A$ is a density point, and almost every $b \in B$ is a density point. For given density points $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ we can find a mutual $r>0$ such that at least 90 percent of $B_r(a)$ is in $A$ (in the sense that $\displaystyle \frac{m(A \cap B_r(A))}{m(B_r(a))}>.9)$, and at least 90 percent of $B_r(b)$ is in $B$. Then since $a$ is a density point of $A$, $-a$ is a density point of $-A$. Moreover, $-a+q$ is a density point of $-A+q$, for an arbitrary $q$. Now, from the density of the rationals, we can find such a $q$ that $|b-(-a+q)| < \displaystyle \frac{r}{100^{100}}$ (this is chosen for dramatic effect). And since $-a+q$ and $b$ were chosen so closely, we know that $B_r(-a+q) \cap B_r(b)$ is nonempty. Thus there are $x \in A$ and $y \in B$ such that $-x+q = y$, and this is what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 0):

*Incorrect answer, but I'm keeping this hoping that part of the arguments can be reused.*

Assume such $A_1,A_2$ exist.  Then they have positive Lebesgue measure.  Similar to the proof in the linked question, define $Q=\Bbb Q\cap[0,1]$.  Note that since all sets here is measurable, so [measure and product are interchangeable](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566048/290189).  (measure of product of measurable sets = product of measures of measurable sets)

---

*As OP points out,$A_1,A_2$ can be unbounded, so the [answer in the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1890257/why-cant-there-be-a-bounded-set-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-such-that-fora) can't be used directly.*

As a result, we are going to show it suffices to consider the case for *bounded* $A_1,A_2$ using the standard truncation argument.

For $i = 1,2, n \in \Bbb{N}$, define $\bbox[2px, border: 1px solid black]{A_i^{(n)}=A_i \cap [-n,n]}$ so that it becomes bounded.  Once we find some $n_1,n_2$ such that $A_1^{(n_1)}, A_2^{(n_2)}$ have positive Lebesgue measure, then the linked proof can be reused in this question.

By the continuity of measure, $n_i\uparrow\infty$, $m(A_i^{(n_i)})\uparrow m(A_i)>0$, so there exists $N_i$ such that $\bbox[2px, border: 1px solid black]{m(A_i^{(N_i)})>0}$.

You have assumed $(A_{1} \times A_{2}) \cap E = \varnothing$, so *a fortiori* $\bbox[2px, border: 1px solid black]{(A_{1}^{(N_1)} \times A_{2}^{(N_2)}) \cap E = \varnothing}$.

To simplify writing and to save ink, I'll strip off the superscript and denote $A_{1}^{(N_1)}$ as $A_1$ since these two unbounded given sets have no role to play in the rest of the proof.

---

\begin{align}
m((r_1+A_1)\times(r_2+A_2))&=m(A_1\times A_2) \forall r_1,r_2\in\Bbb{Q} \\
0<m(Q+A_1)&\le b_1-a_1+1 \\
0<m(Q+A_2)&\le b_2-a_2+1 \\
0<m((Q+A_1)\times(Q+A_2))&=m(Q+A_1)\times m(Q+A_2)\\
&\le (b_1-a_1+1)(b_2-a_2+1)
\end{align}

But
\begin{align}
&m((Q+A_1)\times(Q+A_2))\\
=&\sum_{r_1\in Q}\sum_{r_2\in Q} m(A_1+r_1)\times m(A_2+r_2)\\
=&\sum_{r_1\in Q}\sum_{r_2\in Q} m(A_1)\times m(A_2)\\
=&\infty,
\end{align}
which contradicts the above paragraph.  Therefore, such $A_1,A_2$ don't exist.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no assumption that $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are bounded here.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic Sorry for my wrong assumption, but I'm still not going to delete it since (1) [wrong answer can help us](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4738/290189) in some sense, and (2) I'm going to fix it with the standard truncation argument.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the step $$ m((Q+A_{1}) \times (Q+A_{2})) = \sum_{r_{1} \in Q}\sum_{r_{2}\in Q} m(A_{1} + r_{1}) \times m(A_{2} + r_{2}). $$ Is it because of $$(Q+A_{1}) \times (Q+A_{2}) = \bigsqcup_{(r_{1},r_{2}) \in Q} (r_{1}+A_{1}) \times (r_{2}+A_{2})?$$ I can't get a contradiction by assuming that two of those sets have non-empty intersection.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic There's no need to do so.  Since $Q+A_1$ and $Q+A_2$ are measurable, we can first break it down into $m(\dots)\times m(\dots)$

Comment: I understood the part that you edited; what I'm having trouble with is, for example, proving that $$m(Q+A_{1}) = \sum_{r_{1} \in Q} m(A_{1}+r_{1}).$$ The only way that I can try to prove it is by first proving $$Q+A_{1} = \bigsqcup_{r_{1}\in Q} (A_{1}+r_{1}). $$ But I don't know if this union is disjoint; if I assume the opposite, i.e. that for some $z$ and for some two rationals $r_{1} \neq q_{1}$ we have $z \in A_{1}+r_{1}$ and $z \in A_{1} + q_{1}$, I get $z = a_{1}^{(1)} + r_{1} = a_{2}^{(1)} + q_{1}$, where $a_{1}^{(1)}, a_{2}^{(1)} \in A_{1}$, so...

Comment: $ a_{1}^{(1)} - a_{2}^{(1)} \in \mathbb{Q}$, which would have been a contradiction in the linked question, but it's not a contradiction here, since we're only assuming $a_{1}-a_{2} \notin \mathbb{Q}$ for $a_{1} \in A_{1}$ and $a_{2} \in A_{2}$.

Comment: Sorry for my mistakes.  I really don't know how to prove $$Q+A_{1} = \bigsqcup_{r_{1}\in Q} (A_{1}+r_{1}),$$ but I'm still trying fix it by proofing $$(Q+A_{1}) \times (Q+A_{2}) = \bigsqcup_{(r_{1},r_{2}) \in Q} (r_{1}+A_{1}) \times (r_{2}+A_{2})?$$

Comment: Sorry, I see your point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. It's a consequence of the [Steinhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinhaus_theorem): if $A,B$ have positive measure, then $A-B$ has nonempty interior.

There is an analogous theorem for category, namely $A-B$ has nonempty interior if $A$ and $B$ are both non-meagre.

Comment: Could you explain how it's a consequence? I'm having trouble generalizing it to the two sets being different from one another.

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic: I don't understand. What two sets?

Comment: $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$. According to the Steinhaus theorem on Wikipedia, $A-A$ must have non-empty interior, for any $m(A)>0$. How does one generalize this to $A, B$, $A-B$ having nonempty interior?

Comment: @MatijaSreckovic: Oh, I didn't notice that Wikipedia had the statement for just one set. The simplest argument I know is to notice that $(A\cap (B+r))-(A\cap (B+r))+r\subseteq A-B$, and note that there is some $r$ such that $(A\cap (B+r))$ has positive measure. That follows immediately from Lebesgue's density theorem (strictly speaking, it's enough to show that both $A$ and $B$ have a point with density bigger than $1/2$), I don't know any other argument offhand.